# How to compute joint cdf of an empirical copula? (Updated with more info)

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, copula, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

lets suppose a bivariate empirical copula as:
[image]

for a set of data of example data we can plot it like this:
[image]

How can we compute the joint cdf of this empirical copula which should like this:

[image]
Thank you

Comment: I know there is a function in copula package but I cant figure out how to write it myself.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25682550) help at all? Maybe I don't understand the question, but it seems like it's just a matter of curve/surface fitting.

Comment: The following 2 leads contain code in R of how to do the ranking step, shown in the numerator of the formula you provided, for estimating the empirical copula/joint density: - See the [chosen answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381611/does-the-empirical-transformation-of-the-margins-will-give-copula-data) to this question - Another full-on tutorial is given [here](http://www.deep-mind.org/2017/09/24/empirical_copula/)

Answer (score 3):

Your empirical CDF copula has support in [0,1]^3 (I guess your observations are n ordered triplets). So, I don´t understand your graph: what do you mean by "order" in the horizontal axis?

Comment: I added some more information. I am trying to compute the joint cdf of a set of 3d empirical copula (I said 2d here for simplification) and the order is just sorted data

Comment: @Fred: how do you order 3d data???

Comment: @Xi'an he means a 3D plot of 2 variables. In the second image, axes $x$ and $y$ are the 2 variables, while the 3rd dimension, the vertical axis $z$, is the joint probability value. So the question is about ranking paired observations from 2 variables only, not 3.