# What is bin area during empirical copula estimation?

Tags: copula, binning

Two finite-sampled continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ are transformed so that they are uniformly distributed, $U$ and $V$. With these as marginals, the empirical copula of $X$ and $Y$, denoted $C(u,v)$, can be estimated. The estimation approach being asked here is by discretization via histogram binning.

Since alot of copula theory sticks to just that, theory (integrals, therefore, non-discrete), the discretization implementation is hardly covered. Could someone provide a source from a copula textbook that explains this formula found in the [numpy histogram2d documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

**probability density function at the bin** = `bin_count / sample_count / bin_area`.

By 'at the bin' does this mean there is a distribution formed for each bin? and why the triple fraction? I'm trying to make sense of it for the following:

```
copula_density = np.histogram2d(X_unif, Y_unif, bins, density=True)[0]
copula_freq = np.histogram2d(X_unif, Y_unif, bins, density=False)[0]
bin_area = (copula_freq / copula_density / len(X_unif))[0, 0]
```

since the last line looks like it backs out the `bin_area` from the same equation shown earlier, being a triple fraction also. I also don't know the importance of `bin_area` or what application it would be required for afterwards.

Comment: Probability integral transform (PIT) is used for transforming continuous random variables to uniform, and this is done when working with copulas. I wonder what the justification for other types of transformations is.

Comment: are you saying the binning approach above is different than integral transform (inverse CDF)?

Comment: I don't know. If it were the same, why a different name?

Comment: By *definition,* the density is a value per unit area.  Evidently, then, this *estimate* of the PDF is obtained by estimating *probabilities* as fractions of the sample count.

Comment: "area" to me is length $\times$ width. how does this concept possibly match up with `bin_area = copula_freq / copula_density / len(X_unif)`?